# DIV Overlaying DIV, links in backmost DIV non-accessible

Tags: css, html, overlay

I have a photoshop image that is 500x600 that I am using as a background image for the first div. The second div sits over top of the first div and is populated with images. The z-index of the first div is set to 100.

The effect is the photoshop image sits over top of all of the smaller images. The photoshop image is a letter with the inner-content of it set to be transparent and the small images create the filling.

Each of the small images however is a link, but none of the links are accessible. How can I remedy that?

I would post the code here, but I have absolutely no clue how to format it. I quite simply do not understand typing a backtick followed by the tab key and then a dollar sign. All that ends up is I type a backtick here followed by a dollar sign in the Tags section below.

Comment: Sorry, it's all on a local test-environment.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand the z-index of the "first div" must be < the z-index of the "second div that sits over top".

Comment: Yeah, that lets me click on the small images, but then the background of the first div becomes invisible -- making the effect non-existent.

Comment: How are you applying the background? Are you using an extra div to hold a background?

Comment: Small image DIV -> #front-content {
 width: 500px;
 height: 600px;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
Background image DIV -> #front-bg {
 background: url(../images/r.png) no-repeat;
 width: 505px;
 height: 605px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

Comment: I am all for applying them however in order to achieve the effect I desire.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. from all that I read, it simply is not possible. So, I did this:

load all my images here with unique ids.





  load all my links here based upon same data as first div with unique ids.

I made the links the same size as the images and display: inline-block and it all works. I can now use jQuery hover functions to get the results I want.

Most importantly, no html/css validation was broken. The only downside is my links/images are separated, but still the flow control is legible enough for screen readers.

Comment: probably a good idea, but you can simply hide the photoshop element on hover with css.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add a ":hover" to your css, to make your photoshop image hide when someone tries to click it.

```
.photoshop {z-index:100}
.photoshop:hover {z-index:-1}
```

Comment: I thought about that, but then the entire grid of small-images would appear, also eliminating the effect.

Comment: I did just sort of have an idea though... I wonder if I could on photoshop:hover, quickly set its z-index to -100, immediately increase the z-index of the newly hovered image to 200, then re-set the z-index of photoshop to 100. I wonder what sort of lag I'd be working with.

Comment: Couldn't do it with css.  It would just flicker.

Comment: Oh, I'd be doing it with jQuery. Going to try it out later today.